# How GWT RequestFactory .edit() and sending of deltas work and how to tweak it

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, requestfactory

I noticed that when I invoke

```
    SomeProxy proxyNew = someRequestContext.edit(proxyOld);
    proxyNew.setSomething(somethingNew);
    someRequestContext.mySaveMethod(proxyNew).fire();
```

The entity returned from

```
    @Override //from Locator<SomeEntity ,IdClass>
    public SomeEntity find(Class<? extends SomeProxy > clazz, IdClass id) {
    ...
    }
```

is used in server when saving method is invoked and only those property/istance variable values of proxyNew are transfered to server implementation `mySaveMethod(SomeEntity entity)`which are new in comparison with the returned entity.

Now. I understand that there is some comparison in order to provide server side only with deltas so there is efficiency in communication but I think it is somehow offset by additional processing/transfer time needed by implementation of `public SomeEntity find(Class<? extends SomeProxy > clazz, IdClass id)` which retrieves the entity objects from database.

My question now is, how should this be correctly implemented in system with persistence services exposed via stateless session bean  which provide services to GWT server side servlets/DAO objects. Correctly implemented in a way that the highest efficiency and lowest waiting time is achieved. Also could someone explain to me  this RequestFactory aspect/process  in greater detail?

My example: I retrieve  `OrganizerEntry` entities from persistence layer for a certain day span - a week.

So the method like 
`retrieveOrganizerEntries(Date from, Date to)` is invoked in persistence layer.

Then I see that for each `OrganizerEntry` entity object obtained which is to be sent to the client layer, another query is made, like `retrieveOrganizerEntry(int id)`.

So not only are  the same objects queried twice, but  the second time they are queried one by one in a very inefficient manner.

How can this be improved? Should I cache in DAO/servlet objects somehow the results from first query and let  `public SomeEntity find(Class<? extends SomeProxy > clazz, IdClass id)`  search the cache? Is it way to go to implement this method returning  `null` or 
newly created empty entity (`new OrganizerEntity()`) and before invoking the persist/save method from the client just setting every single property/instance variable value?

Where can I find more examples and explanation about this stuff? Because http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html seems to me not very exhausting .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Regarding the `rf` internals, you can refer to this [document](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryMovingParts). But I guess Thomas Broyer is going to respond to this in more detail.

The basic flow is following:

- properties that are modifed through the setter are transmitted to the server.
- server uses `find()` to retrieve the entity and calls the corresponding `setters` (whatever you also called on the client).
- Validation rules are processed
- The entity is passed to your service method.

2.) With `RF` you need `one session per http request` aka [OpenSessioninview pattern](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView). . 
The first level cache of your persistence layer (i.e. Hibernate) should make multiple redundant calls to `find()` really efficient so you usually will only hit the database once during the session`s lifetime.

3.) If you don't care about `EntityProxyChange` events on the client you could override the `isLive()` method of your `Locator` and just return `true` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886949/gwt-request-factory-multiple-queries-for-collection-from-the-servicelayerdeco) for more details).   That's also probably the reason why the `find()` method is called when you retrieve a list of `OrganizerEntry` instances because for each `OrganizerEntry` `RF` checks if it's still alive by calling 'isLive()' which itself calls `find()`.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation Uemit. So there are two ways to go:               A) to have one session with  persistance layer / `EntityManager` per http request - this would involve some interceptors or stateful session beans? Right now the calls to JPA are via stateless session  beans for CRUD operations.                                                                    B) "Turning off" invocation of `find()` by overriding `isLive()` to return always `true`. I wonder, what I am losing here with this approach? What is the catch? What exactly are 'EntityProxyChange' events?

Comment: A.) Yes the `OpenSessionview` pattern is the right approach. Unfortunately I have no experience with JavaEE but with `Spring` you just need to add a servlet filter.

Comment: B.) `EntityProxyChange` events are useful when you want to notify the client that an entity has been changed/deleted. (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476341/requestfactory-theory-why-is-locator-find-being-called-so-often) for more details). If you override `isLive()` and return `true` you won't get those events on the client. Most people probably don't care about those `Events`.

Comment: So I am sacrificing events received from server side to client when the entity has changed so I can have simpler architecture and faster loading (even with `OpenSessionView` there must be some increased overhead, oder?). What are the advantages of having `Events` anyway?  If data are edited by more users at the same time? I must say that overriding `isLive()` helped, but I am still confused and don`t understand how RT works. Now I don`t see `find()` called at all even when persisting `Entity`.

Comment: Properly reacting to Events (i.e. an entiy was deleted by another user) and keeping the system und UX simple is quite difficult. That's probably the reason why most people don't rely on the `EntityProxyChange` events. The last user who saves the entiy "wins" is a common approach. 
Even if you override the `isLive()` method `find()` should be called when you persist the entity. if it's not called then I guess nothing has changed (no setter was called).

Comment: You are right. The `find()` method is called. So even when I have overriden `isLive()`, thus effectively turning off the 'Events feature', I still need the server code to have invocation of `find()` and custom `saveEntity()` in one session with persistence provider. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you need the `find()` method otherwise you the object that is passed to your service method `saveEntity()` will be null.

Comment: I know this. I meant, that having two separate persistence sessions for find() and saveEntity() is just a bad design in general or is this acceptable?

Comment: you should have on session and possibly actually one transaction which wraps all the calls to the persistence layer. You can do this by extending the `RequestFactoryServlet` and starting a transaction and commiting it at the end.